# Python: Hawaiian word pronouncing (misplaced hyphens)

Tags: python

am supposed to make a program that takes in a inputted Hawaiian word and outputs the pronunciation. While my code is using the correct letters to pronounce the word it is placing the hyphens in the wrong spots.

Rules:

p,k,h,l,m,n are pronounced the same as they are in English.
W as the start of the word or after the letter a, u, or o is pronounced as a w. but if it is after the letter i or e it is pronounced as a v.
for vowels: a is pronounced as "ah", e as "eh", i as "ee" , o as "oh" , u as "oo"
for groups vowels: ai is pronounced "eye", ae is "eye" , ao is "ow" , au is "ow" , ei is "ay" , eu is "eh-oo" , iu is "ew" , oi is "oyo" , ou is "ow" and ui is "ooey"

below is my code:

```
vowels = {"a":"ah","e":"eh", "i":"ee","o":"oh","u":"oo"}
doubleVowels = {"ai":"eye","ae":"eye","ao":"ow","eu":"eh-oo","ei":"ay","au":"ow","iu":"ew","oi":"oyo","ou":"ow","ui":"ooey"}
cons =  "wphkmln"

def validate(validLetters, word):
    for letter in word:
        letter = letter.lower()
        if validLetters.count(letter) == 0:
            print (letter, "is a invalid hawaiian character")
            return False
    return True

def pronounce(word):
    output = ""
    vowels_str = "aeiou"
    i = 0
    while i < len(word):
        if i > 0 and ((word[i] in vowels_str and word[i - 1] in vowels_str + cons) or (word[i] in cons and word[i - 1] in vowels_str)):
            output += "-"
        if i < len(word) - 1 and word[i:i + 2] in doubleVowels:
            output += doubleVowels[word[i:i + 2]]
            i += 2
        elif i < len(word) - 2 and word[i:i + 3] in doubleVowels:
            output += doubleVowels[word[i:i + 3]]
            i += 3
        elif word[i] in vowels:
            output += vowels[word[i]]
            i += 1
        elif word[i] in cons:
            if word[i] == 'w':
                if i == 0 or word[i - 1] in 'au':
                    output += 'w'
                elif word[i - 1] in 'ie':
                    output += 'v'
            else:
                output += word[i]
            i += 1
        elif word[i] == "'":
            output += "'"
            i += 1
        elif word[i] == " ":
            output += " "
            i += 1
    return output.capitalize()

def main():
    valid_hawaiian_characters = "aeiouwphkmln' "
    done = False
    while not done:
        gaveValidWord = False
        while not gaveValidWord:
            word = input("give word: ").lower()
            gaveValidWord = validate(valid_hawaiian_characters, word)
```

Current Output:

```
give word: aloha
Pronunciation: Ah-l-oh-h-ah
go again? yes
give word: keikikane
Pronunciation: K-ay-k-ee-k-ah-n-eh
go again? yes
give word: humuhumunukunukuapua'a
Pronunciation: H-oo-m-oo-h-oo-m-oo-n-oo-k-oo-n-oo-k-oo-ah-p-oo-ah'ah
go again? no
```

intended:

```
Input: aloha -> Output: Ah-loh-hah
Input: keikikane -> Output: Kay-kee-kah-neh
Input: humuhumunukunukuapua'a -> Output: Hoo-moo-hoo-moo-noo-koonoo-koo-ah-poo-ah'ah
Input: e komo mai -> Output: Eh koh-moh meye
```

Comment: I was playing around with your code and found a solution by just using `(not (word[i] in vowels_str and word[i - 1] in vowels_str + cons) or ...` in your first if statement :) You would still need to fix spaces adding hyphens when they aren't supposed to, but it's a step forward.